# About accessing the section header in the ELF file

Tags: c, linux, reverse-engineering, elf

I am reading a tutorial about accessing the elf files using C, the link is [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial).

In the section **Accessing Section Headers**, it says that section headers can be accessed by the following code:

```
static inline Elf32_Shdr *elf_sheader(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr) {
    return (Elf32_Shdr *)((int)hdr + hdr->e_shoff);
}
 
static inline Elf32_Shdr *elf_section(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr, int idx) {
    return &elf_sheader(hdr)[idx];
}
```

But the `e_shoff` in the ELF header is the offset of the section header, why it should be added up with the value of `hdr` in the function `elf_sheader` to get the section header's address?

Comment: `e_shoff` is a byte offset from the start of the file header, so you have to add that offset to the base address of the header to get the memory address of the base of the section headers.

Comment: so is that right to treat the address of ELF header as the base address of the every offsets in the elf header?

Comment: Unless explicitly specified, all offsets in an ELF file are typically file offsets; so, if you mmapped the ELF file to some memory address, offset 0 of the mmapped region will be the address of the ELF header, and therefore the base address to which you have to add offsets to.